# Error when running Firebase in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, firebase

I am playing around with Firebase and I am trying to print the value of an item in Swift. This is the only code in the whole application, so nothing really complicated is going on.

```
var myRootRef = Firebase(url:"https://jotty.firebaseio.com/")

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    myRootRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {

        snapshot in
        println(snapshot.value)

    })

}
```

When I run this I get an error:

```
2015-07-15 12:15:03.492 Jotty[32431:733653] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[FRepo youForgotToSetMinusObjCInTheOtherLinkerFlagsInYourXCodeProject]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b28b7a0'
```

Would anyone know how to fix this? I have been trying to fix this all day but I have no idea what is wrong with the application.

Comment: "`youForgotToSetMinusObjCInTheOtherLinkerFlagsInYourXCodeProject`" -> You Forgot To Set -ObjC In The Other Linker Flags In Your XCode Project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In "Build Settings" under "Other Linker Flags" use the "-ObjC" flag.

[image]

**[I recommend using CocoaPods](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/quickstart.html) instead of a manual setup**.

[See the Firebase docs for a manual setup](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/alternate-setup.html).